# Difference between (^|\\s)([A-Z]{1,3})(\\s|$) and \\b[A-Z]{1,2}\\b regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying clean some small strings (1-3 letters) stored in a column from R Data Frame. Specifically, suppose the next R Script:

```
df = data.frame( "original" = c("ABCDE FG H",
                            "IJKL MN OPQRS", 
                            "TUV WX YZ AAAA"))
df$filter1 = gsub("(^|\\s)[A-Z]{1,2}($|\\s)", " ", df$original)
df$filter2 = gsub("\\b[A-Z]{1,2}\\b", " ", df$original)

> df

        original |    filter1 |    filter2  |
1     ABCDE FG H |    ABCDE H |    ABCDE    |
2  IJKL MN OPQRS | IJKL OPQRS | IJKL   OPQRS|
3 TUV WX YZ AAAA | TUV YZ AAAA|  TUV   AAAA |
```

I don't understand why the first filter `(^|\\s)[A-Z]{1,2}($|\\s)` doesn't replace "H" in the first row or "YZ" in the third one. I would expect the same result that using `\\b[A-Z]{1,2}\\b` as filter (filter2 column). Please don't worry about multiple spaces, it isn't important for me (unless this would be the problem :)).

I thought that the problem is the "globality" of operation, that it's, if it finds the first one not replace the second one, but it isn't TRUE if I do the next replacement:

```
> gsub("A", "X", "AAAABBBBCCCDDDDAAAAAAAEEE")
[1] "XXXXBBBBCCCDDDDXXXXXXXEEE"
```

So, Why are the results different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that `gsub` can only match *non-overlapping* strings.  `FG`  being the first expected match, and  `H` the second, you can see that these strings *overlap*, and thus, after `"(^|\\s)[A-Z]{1,2}($|\\s)"` consumes the trailing space after `FG`, `H` just does not match the pattern.

Look: `ABCDE FG H` is analyzed from left to right. The expression matches  `FG` , and the regex index is right before `H`. There is only this letter to match, but `(^|\s)` requires a space or the start of string - there is none at this location.

To "fix" this and use the same logic, you can use a PCRE regex `gsub` with *lookarunds*:

```
df$filter1 = gsub("(^|\\s)[A-Z]{1,2}(?=$|\\s)", " ", df$original, perl=TRUE)
```

or

```
df$filter1 = gsub("(?<!\\S)[A-Z]{1,2}(?!\\S)", " ", df$original, perl=TRUE)
```

and if you need to actually consume (to remove) spaces, just add `\\s*` before (or/and after).

The second expression `"\\b[A-Z]{1,2}\\b"` contains word boundaries, and they are zero-width assertions that do not consume text, thus, the regex engine can match both `FG` and `H` since the spaces are not consumed.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. If I understand well, the replacement takes place in each step and it's necessary to indicate _lookarounds_ to take into account the whole string in each search, isn't it? Thank you again.

Comment: No, the point is that `gsub` can only match *non-overlapping* strings. " FG " being the first expected match, and " H" the second, you can see that these strings *overlap*. I updated the explanation at the top of my answer.

Comment: And as for lookarounds, they are *zero-width assertions*, that is, the regex index stays where it is after matching the consuming pattern before the lookaround. Then, the regex engines looks "ahead" or "behind", to check if a text meeting the pattern is present, and only returns true or false, failing or allowing a match at the current location.

Comment: Perfect, I think that it's actually the problem. I'm going to read more about lookarounds. Thank you.